# is it good to use try-finally just to make sure that something is performed when method finished?

Tags: c#

My method returns in many points. I construct newData during execution also in many points. Regardless of where I return I need to save and store constructed result. Not to miss "return" I just surrounded the code with try-finally block so now I'm sure that newData will be stored.

```
List<X> newData = new List<X>();
try
{
    ....
    update newData
    .....
    return;
    .....
    ....
    update newData
    ....
    update newData
    return;
    .....
    return;
} finally
{
    // copy newData to data    
}
```

But I don't catch any exceptions and this code is not intended to work with exceptions. Is it acceptable in general or you can suggest another better approach?

Comment: That looks like you could use a [switch statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). I don't see why you need to return immediately.

Comment: It's only acceptable if it works as intended. If it doesn't work, try refactoring it into smaller functions. If it does, what's the big deal? I can't give any specific suggestions without seeing more detailed source code.

Comment: Unless someone pulls the plug, the `finally` block is executed in any case and your code will work as expected; however, as other have pointed out already, there are better ways to structure your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest refactoring the code within the `try` block into a new method:

```
data = CreateList();

...

private List<X> CreateList()
{
    List<X> list = new List<X>();
    // It's fine to return list from any point here...
}
```

Comment: This is almost what I was going to suggest: I would add that in some cases, when for readability it's better to put the `CreateList` body inside the other method, an `Action` delegate can be used from which a `return` only exits that anonymous method.

Answer (score 2):

The usage of finally is intended as a backup if something fails(think of it as a fail-safe mechanism), including atomicity etc.

Generally the whole construction of your method is wrong and you can refactor it, as getting all those returns usually means you can take up another approach to things(example using a switch as someone in the comments suggested).

Comment: `switch` is not what i need. code inside has many branches and hard to refactor as logic is not trivial